# java multithread reading..please help im very new to java:(

Tags: java, multithreading

Program that demonstrates the use of multithread reading with the use of three counters with three threads defined for each. Thus threads should represent the counters as follows:

1. One counter starts from 5 and increments with the step of 5.
2. Second counter starts from 10 and increments with the step of 10.
3. Third counter starts with 100 and increments with the step of 100.
4. Assign proper priority to the threads and then run the threads.

Comment: Perhaps if you asked a real question instead of posting your homework problem straight off?

Comment: Are you sure you don't want to add the homework tag? This smells like a standard CS homework assignment.

Comment: I for one think that it's a beautiful assignment -- many thanks for sharing this with us. I'm sure that I speak for all in wishing you luck in completing it.

Comment: Priority in Java threads generally doesn't do what you think it might and varies between OS.  I wouldn't suggest you use Thread priorities.

Comment: yup its a homework..im stuck with the phrase that we have to demonstrate multi thread READING...im confused that do we have to read something 5 then 10 then 100 times??? sorry cant ask ny teacher as this is distant studies:(

Answer (score 2):

Even if you're very new to java, it should be easy to use google to get a idea how this problem can be solved, it's not very complicated.

Just have a look [at this example about threading](http://www.javabeginner.com/learn-java/java-threads-tutorial), it was the first hit. Check out the [table of contents](http://www.javabeginner.com/toc.htm) on javabeginner.com to learn more, I really recommend it to you.

Answer (score 2):

The [Java Tutorial Concurrency Lesson](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/index.html) is a great place to start learning about multithreading.

Answer (score 2):

The question is not clear but since this is a homework, I will just give hints

1. Read the [multi-threading tutorial](http://www.deitel.com/articles/java_tutorials/20051126/JavaMultithreading_Tutorial_Part1.html) first
2. thread priorities may not show the same behavior across OS's

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you create an ExecutorService and add three tasks to the service with one loop for each task. I could give you an answer, but unless you do some investigation yourself, you won't understand it.